# How to call custom authentication library method in Azure Function Startup?

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am trying to create an Azure Function (using `NET 6.0 and Azure Functions runtime 4.0`) and want to use a custom authentication library method `AddAzureAdAuthentication` that exists in my shared library just like how I was able to use it in this `.Net Core api` to authenticate api endpoints:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAzureAdAuthentication(Configuration);
        services.AddCorsConfiguration(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I have read many articles and SO posts, but none gave a working solution to this problem. This is what I tried so far -

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
    var currentDirectory = executionContextOptions.AppDirectory;

    // Get the original configuration provider from the Azure Function
    var configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();

    // Create a new IConfigurationRoot and add our configuration along with Azure's original configuration 
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
        .AddConfiguration(configuration) // Add the original function configuration 
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    // Replace the Azure Function configuration with our new one
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

    ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
}

private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAzureAdAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
}
```

and my HttpTriggered Azure Function is a default function:

```
[FunctionName("TestADFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
        : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

When I hit the function, it runs always without authenticating. I am not sure how to make this call to `UseAuthentication();`. I guess that is what is missing. Or, is there any other way to authenticate and authorize my azure function using my custom auth library?

Comment: I don't understand your goal.  You can easily configure authentication for a Function App in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirements in your Function app , Need to add `nuget package` called [**`Microsoft.Identity.Web`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web/)

And in `startup.cs` we can use the below sample code:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionsAuthentication.Startup))]
namespace FunctionsAuthentication
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // This is configuration from environment variables, settings.json etc.
            var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = "Bearer";
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bearer";
            })
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
        }
    }
}
```

And in `local settings.json` we need to provide the credentials of our `Azure AD`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureAd:Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "AzureAd:Domain": "<your_domain>",
    "AzureAd:TenantId": "<your_tenant_id>",
    "AzureAd:ClientId": "<client_id>",
    "AzureAd:ClientSecret": "<client_secret>"
  }
}
```

For complete setup please refer to this [***Blog***](https://hajekj.net/2020/12/12/microsoft-identity-web-and-azure-functions/)